# How to set global variable to material design lite library in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, material-design-lite

I'm using Googles "Material Design Lite" library with Microsoft's TypeScript inside of Visual Studio 2015.  I have a script tag in my Index.html page as so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
```

Inside one of my typescript modules I hacked in a variable to get access to the Material Design Lite (MDL) library functions as so:

```
module Default {
  'use strict';

   export var componentHandler = window['componentHandler'];
```

This works as shown below to update the MDL DOM, but I would prefer a more elegant way.  This way seems really "hacky".  Is there some way to create this global variable to the MDL functions in a typescript definition file?

```
Default.componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inside one of my typescript modules I hacked in a variable to get access to the Material Design Lite (MDL) library functions as so

The library exposes itself to the *global namespace*. This is evidenced by your usage : `window['componentHandler']`

So to be *correct* create a file `globals.d.ts` or `vendor.d.ts` and *declare* this fact:

```
/** From MDL */
declare var componentHandler: any;
```

## More :

Quick migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Globals pattern: 
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/globals.html

Comment: Yep.  Thanks for the quick response.  That fixed it.  It's no wonder you have a 50,000 reputation.  Do you know if it is a bad thing that I am using script tags to pull in my external libraries and then using the built-in Visual Studio bundling for my typescript modules?  I hate NPM.

Comment: Sadly NPM is the future. And hopefully its the *only* future for JavaScript. You wouldn't use Nuget for Haskell then why use it for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a version of material-design-lite.d.ts and added the typescript include reference;

```
///<reference path="material-design-lite.d.ts"/>
```

Pete.